# What version of Starbound am I playing?

Tags: starbound

Starbound 1.0 has been released, but when I launch the game on Steam the game's title still says "Starbound - Beta". How can I find out whether I'm running the 1.0 version of the game?

Comment: You're leaving information out of your question, the OS should always be specified in case of multiplatform games.

Comment: @user598527 For a simple question like this I don't think there's any point in having a different question for every platform

Comment: Just wanted to point it out, the fact that the title of the window still said "Starbound - Beta" was a bug and has been fixed in version 1.0.1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The game menu (default: <kbd>ESC</kbd>) will show the version:

[image: Menu showing "Starbound - 1.0 (windows x86_64)"]

Comment: Also note that it seems there's no way of seeing the menu without actually starting a game.